# "aggregate" function inside of "ifelse" statement in R

Tags: r, aggregate-functions

I am trying to used "aggregate" function inside of "ifelse" statement in R. 
I want to return NA if min sale is equal to 0 then if not aggregate it. like the codes below:

```
 df <- data.frame(day=c("Mon","Tue","Mon","Tue","Tue","Tue"),sales=c(799,1359,1359,1359,1359,1359))
df2 <- ifelse(min(df$sales)==0,NA,aggregate(sales~day,data=df,sum))
```

My problem is that it return this:

```
[[1]]
[1] Mon Tue
Levels: Mon Tue
```

I want it to to return a data frame like usually aggregate:

```
 day sales
1 Mon  2158
2 Tue  5436
```

Comment: Use `if(cond) ... else ...` instead of `ifelse`

Comment: @jbest An option using `data.table` `setDT(df)[, if(min(sales)!=0) sum(sales) else NA_integer_ , day]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @A.Webb's comment, I think you want to put the `if` inside `aggregate` using an anonymous function:

```
aggregate(sales ~ day, data=df, function(x) if(min(x)==0) NA else sum(x) )
```